# Dpkg - doesn't create folder while installing deb package

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, dpkg

This is my first attempt to create own package from sources. How I did it:

```
fakeroot
make install DESTDIR=/home/user/temp
cd /home/user/temp
mkdir DEBIAN
find etc | sed "s/^/\//" > DEBIAN/conffiles
```

After that I created DEBIAN/control file and run `dpkg -b /home/user/temp`. After that I have deb package and as a real root I do `dpkg -i /home/user/temp.deb`. However, dpkg doesn't copy files from deb package to fs but it complains that such folders don't exist ( No such file or directory). As I understand it must create folders as they are in DEBIAN/CONTENTS but it doesn't. What do I miss?

**EDIT** I tried to add file DEBIAN/dirs with list of paths:

```
/etc
/etc/selinux/
/etc/selinux/refpolicy
...
```

But it didn't help ( I tried with leading / and without leading /)

**EDIT** Command `dpkg-deb -c temp.deb` has the following output

```
drwxr-xr-x user/user       0 2016-09-08 10:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x user/user       0 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x user/user       0 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/
drwxr-xr-x user/user       0 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/refpolicy/
drwxr-xr-x user/user       0 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/refpolicy/src/
drwxr-xr-x user/user       0 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/refpolicy/src/policy/
drwxr-xr-x user/user       0 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/refpolicy/src/policy/support/
-rw-r--r-- user/user    6176 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/refpolicy/src/policy/support/Makefile.devel
-rw-r--r-- user/user       6 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/refpolicy/src/policy/support/undivert.m4
-rw-r--r-- user/user      12 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/refpolicy/src/policy/support/divert.m4
-rw-r--r-- user/user   10673 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/refpolicy/src/policy/support/pyplate.py
-rw-r--r-- user/user   13796 2016-09-08 10:57 ./etc/selinux/refpolicy/src/policy/support/fc_sort.c
..... etc
```

And here what I get:

```
error creating directory `./etc/selinux/refpolicy/src': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you have marked directories as `conffiles` in the `DEBIAN/conffiles` file. This is not supported and does break. Recent(ish) versions of `dpkg-deb` will warn in those cases.

Also the `DEBIAN/dirs` file is of no use here, I guess this is a confusion with the one under the source directory debian/dirs, used by `debhelper`.